# How to implement checkstyle to spock testing?

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spock, checkstyle

I have added checkstyle.xml file in my spring boot project. it`s checking my java files but not working for groovy files. I want spock test files to be checked.

I have added test file path in gradle file

```
checkstyleTest {
source ='src/test/groovy' 
}
```

I also added groovy extension to checkstyle.xml file

```
<property name="fileExtensions" value="java, properties, xml, groovy"/>
```

Comment: Which checks do you have in your configuration? Anything inside `TreeWalker` will not run on groovy files, only those outside it will which are basically just text parsers. There is no parser for groovy in checkstyle.

Comment: You'd normally use Codenarc for groovy code.